# Add data above index pandas and write to excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So the dataframe I have is like this,

```
                     
Status                  Count      
Success                   2
Error                     2
```

I set the index to status column, but thats not all what i need.
I need to display something like this, with some text above index name.

```
Complete Data Backup  
Status                 Count     
Success                   2
Error                     2
```

So far, Ive tried this code which displayed the format I want, but it doesnt appear in excel when I write to excel using `df1.to_excel()`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Status').rename_axis('Complete Data Backup', axis=1)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Status": ["Success", "Error"], "Count": [2, 2]})

print(df)
# Output
    Status  Count
0  Success      2
1    Error      2
```

Here is one way to do it using [advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing):

```py
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [("Complete Data Backup",), ("Status", "Count")]
)

print(df)
# Output
  Complete Data Backup      
                Status Count
0              Success     2
1                Error     2
```

And then:

```py
df.to_excel("file.xlsx")
```

In `file.xlsx`:

[image]

Comment: can you also let me know why there is an empty row at 3?
Also how can i remove the index column?

Comment: I understand the  empty row is by design. And, as of the date of this comment, it is not possible to save to Excel and drop index at the same time (using index=False) when columns are multi-index too. Cheers.